# Writing formula into Excel through Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I want to insert in "A1" some text "ABC" and the following cell in "B1" an `if` statement. However I get only the first entry "ABC" inserted and then an error at `FormulaR1C2 "Object doesn't support this property or method"`. I'm not sure I'm using the `R1C2` correctly. I was assuming it stood for Row 1 Column 2, can someone help me out.

```
Dim Excel_App  As Object
Dim strExcel As String
Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Excel_App.Visible = True
Excel_App.Workbooks.Add
With Excel_App
 .Range("A:B").EntireRow.ColumnWidth = 25
 .Range("A2").EntireRow.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
 .ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ABC"
  strExcel = "=IF(A1 = """"," & """EMPTY""" & "," & """FILLED""" & ") "
 .ActiveCell.FormulaR1C2 = strExcel
End With
```

Comment: Would you be willing to setup a NamedRange/Table?  Would be alot easier to transpose information from Access to a NamedRange/Table, so that way if the Range location moves, you wont have to necessarily go into the Output logic and change all the Row/Col locations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FormulaR1C1` is the method of how the formula is written.

`Formula` refers to writing a formula in A1 like `=B1+C1`.

To write that same formula using `R1C1` notation, you would write `=RC[1] + RC[2]`. Furthermore to write `=B2+C2` in A1 write this `=R[1]C[1] + R[1]C[2]` -> so you can see you are offsetting the columns and rows where you want the formula to return values from.

What you want to do in your code is offset the place where the formula will be placed, rather than how it's calculating, so you should write this:

```
.ActiveCell.Offset(,1).Formula = strExcel
```

Actually, you should get rid of `ActiveCell` altogether, unless you absolutely need it.

I would write your code like this for better, more accurate execution:

```
Dim Excel_App As Object
Dim strExcel As String
Dim wkb as Object, wks as Object

Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Excel_App.Visible = True
Set wkb = Excel_App.Workbooks.Add
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1) 'assumes you want first sheet, can modify for sheet index or name

With wks

 .Range("A:B").EntireRow.ColumnWidth = 25 
  'I think this will actually set every row to 25, is that what you want?

 .Range("A2").EntireRow.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"

 .Range("A1").Value = "ABC" 'don't need to write Value, but just to show you the property

  strExcel = "=IF(A1 = """"," & """EMPTY""" & "," & """FILLED""" & ") "

 .Range("B1").Formula = strExcel

End With
```

Comment: @user1090656 -> please mark it as answered if it satisfied your needs, so that others may benefit! Also, please see my updated answer. It may benefit you greatly.

Comment: @user1090656 -> I edited again. I forget to reference the worksheet! :(

Comment: What about formulas for Tables/Lists. Currently have a formula for list that looks like "=[@Turnover]/SUM([Turnover])" where "Turnover" is the title in Excel list. It gives Error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error. Is there anything I should escape in the string?

Answer (score 0):

`FormulaR1C1` is a property which  returns the formula of a cell expressed in `R1C1` formula style.

You need to reference `cells` by using the `Workbook.WorkSheet.Range` syntax.

So first you need to specify the workbook you are working in, which in your case is the workbook added by the statement `Excel_App.Workbooks.Add`. Your new workbook is automatically named something like "Book1" and automatically has the default number of worksheets added named "Sheet1" through "Sheetn" where n is the default number of sheets.

So you're final code to write to that line is

```
Excel_App.Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "ABC"
Excel_App.Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Formula = "=IF(A1 = """"," & """EMPTY""" & "," & """FILLED""" & ")"
```