# Adding a format condition in Excel through Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

So currently i got these lines in my code,

```
.Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(B2 = """"," & """REQUIRED""" & "," & """""" & ") "
.Range("C3").Formula = "=IF(B3 = """"," & """REQUIRED""" & "," & """""" & ") "
```

my goal was to add a conditional formatting to it, so if it equal to Required from the range =$C$2:$C$3 turn background red so far ive seen some codes online but none of them seem to apply. I modified some existing code for my purposes by i get an error on xlExpression "variable not defined". Can anyone help me?

```
.Range("C2:C3").Selection.FormatConditions.Delete 
.Range("C2:C3").Selection.FormatConditions.Add TYPE:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=(=$C$2:$C$23 = 'REQUIRED')"
```

Comment: try `recording a macro` as you apply the conditional formatting manually. This should provide the syntax you need to get to solve your riddle :)

Comment: I've gotten the code however @ScottHoltzman do you remember my previous question i am adding this within the SUB, and i am still getting the error  "variable not defined" on the  xlExpression

Comment: the code generated when recorded  Range("C2").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$C$2=""REQUIRED"""

Comment: What does this have to do with Access? If nothing, please remove the Access tags.

Comment: @Remou its coded in Access 2007, should it still not be in access ???

Comment: 1 thing I can think of is to make sure the version of the XL application that you are opening in your Access database is compatible with the syntax `Type:=xlExpression` If you are running XL2003, it may very well not be.

Comment: If it is coded in MS Access, do you have a reference to the Excel library? If not, you will have to substitute the constants for values. For example, xlExpression  = 2

Comment: I'm running on the MS 2007 access and excel, i am assuming the  reference to the Excel library was automated since i was able to do other excel methods as "Range("C2").Formula " and "value" if not i will look into that.

Comment: Range is a property of an object, but xlExpression is a built-in constant, so you can refer to one without a library, but not the other.

Comment: @Remou is right. I remember from your previous post that you used late binding so you will need to use the values instead of the constant. For more on early vs. late binding, see [this](http://www.dicks-clicks.com/excel/olBinding.htm). If you use early binding, you'll be able to use the constants, because you are setting a reference directly to the XL application library. It would also be code to post a link to your other question, so others viewing this will be able to follow in the future.

Comment: @Remou and Scott Holtzman thank you for the help! and to anyone reading this the link to my previous question which is @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/13123588/1090656

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace xlExpression with 2.