# 2010 Access VBA setting conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: ms-access-2010

I found this answer for an Excel VBA, but I'm having trouble converting it to Access VBA ([Conditional Formatting using Excel VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661965/conditional-formatting-using-excel-vba-code)).

Here's my current code:

```
    with ws
         With .Cells(1, 1).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IF($J2=""Y"";TRUE;FALSE)")
            .Font.Color = -10092544
            .StopIfTrue = False
            StrSearchCriteria = "A2:D" & lRow
            .FormatConditions(1).ModifyAppliesToRange Range(StrSearchCriteria)
        End With
        With .Cells(1, 1).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""Closed (New)""")
            .Font.Color = -16776961
            .StopIfTrue = False
            StrSearchCriteria = "A2:K" & lRow
            .FormatConditions(2).ModifyAppliesToRange Range(StrSearchCriteria)
        End With
    End With
```

I'm getting the error "Invalid procedure call or argument".

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125467/adding-a-format-condition-in-excel-through-access-vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to reference the selection. Try:

`.Range("A:D").FormatConditions.Delete`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you Erin!

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer: [Adding a format condition in Excel through Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125467/adding-a-format-condition-in-excel-through-access-vba).

However, when I simply try to delete any existing conditional formats (as a test of the method with code from the linked answer) I receive the error "Object does not support this property or method."  The code is:

```
with wks
    .Range("A:D").Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
end with
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.